# Azure Terraform Unable to Set secret in KeyVault during deployment

Tags: azure-devops, terraform-provider-azure

I am facing a blocker that I don't seem to find a practical solution.

I am using azure terraform to create a storage account, and I would like, during the release pipeline, to be able to set the connection string of this storage account as a secret in an existing KeyVault.

So far I am able to retrieve secret from this KeyVault as I am using a `managed identity` which has the following permission upon the KeyVault:

```
key = get, list
secret = get, list and set
cert = get , list
```

the workflow process in my terraform is as follow:

Retrieve the KeyVault data:

```
data "azurerm_key_vault" "test" {
  name                = "test"
  resource_group_name = "KeyVault-test"
}
```

Retrieve the user assigned identity data:

```
data "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "example" {
  name                = "mng-identity-example"
  resource_group_name = "managed-identity-example"
}
```

Once I have those 2 data, I tried to create the secret as follow:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "secretTest" {

  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.test.id
  name         = "secretTest"
  value        = azurerm_storage_account.storageaccount.primary_connection_string


}
```

Once I set the release pipeline to run this terraform, it does fail with the error `Access Denied`

Which is fully understandable as this terraform does not have permission to set or retrieve the secret.

And this is the part on which I am blocked.

If anyone can help understand how can I use my managed identity to set this secret?

I looked into terraform documentation but couldn't find any step or explanation.

Thank you so much for your help and time, and please if you need more info just ask me.

Comment: hello @Nayden Van , to understand here can you please tell if  you are using the same managed identity to login to azure / while performing the terraform apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that the ***service principal that you are using to login into Azure*** using Terraform has the ***same permission which you assigned to the managed identity*** .

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}

  subscription_id = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  client_id       = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ## This Client ID needs to have the permissions in Keyvault access policy which you have provided to the managed identity.
  client_secret   = var.client_secret
  tenant_id       = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
}
```

### OR

If You are using a ***Service Connection*** to connect the Devops Pipeline to Azure and use it in Terrafarom , then you need to provide that ***Devops service connection*** (service principal) the ***permissions in the access policy***.